# Alternative to Nagios for monitoring custom alerts

Tags: notifications, monitoring, alert

I don't want to monitor network traffic, CPU usage, memory usage, disk usage, etc. The only thing I want to monitor are custom alerts/notifications from applications.

I also don't want to monitor logs or just log information.

I want to send messages to a system that will record them and report them to me.

Is there anything that is simple/small that provides this functionality with a web portal? I would just send a message to it, it saves it in its own local database and I can track the issues with a web portal?

I've tried OpenNMS and Shinken today and they didn't seem to fit.

Answer (score 0):

NetXMS could be your system of choice for this because:

- It's easy to deploy ("simple")
- It's lightweight in default configuration and can use sqlite if you dont require full-featured db ("small")
- The server can run on Unix or Windows (you didn't specify your platform)
- It doesn't monitor parameters unless a user tells to do so
- You can view alerts in a desktop GUI and in a Web GUI
- If you have a need to extend your app monitoring functionality in the future there are plenty of features so you won't have to switch to anything else

You didn't specify how your applications send these notifications so I assume you have  programming control on how they can do it. If this is the case then you can either use NetXMS APIs right from your apps code to deliver these notifications or just call event sending command packaged along with the NetXMS server.

Comment: Let me check it out. Thanks for the suggestion!